# How do I specify a source in build requests using gcloud container builds submit?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-container-registry, google-container-builder

I am trying to specify a build request with the `source` specified as a `repoSource`:

```
{                                                                                                                                                                                                         
    "source": {                                                                                                                                                                                           
        "repoSource": {                                                                                                                                                                                   
            "repoName": "myRepo",                                                                                                                                                                           
            "branchName": "master"                                                                                                                                                                        
        }                                                                                                                                                                                                 
    },                                                                                                                                                                                                    
    "steps": [                                                                                                                                                                                            
        {                                                                                                                                                                                                 
            "name": "gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker",                                                                                                                                                       
            "args": ["build", "-t", "gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/zookeeper", "."]                                                                                                                                  
        }                                                                                                                                                                                                 
    ],                                                                                                                                                                                                    
    "images": [                                                                                                                                                                                           
        "gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/zookeeper"                                                                                                                                                                    
    ]                                                                                                                                                                                                     
}
```

However, when I attempt to submit it with gcloud, I get an error:

```
$ gcloud container builds submit --no-source --config cloudbuild.json
ERROR: (gcloud.container.builds.submit) cloudbuild.json: config cannot specify source
```

In ["Writing Custom Build Requests"](https://cloud.google.com/container-builder/docs/how-to/writing-build-requests) it says:

> When you submit build requests using the gcloud command-line tool, the source field may not be necessary if you specify the source as a command-line argument. You may also specify a source in your build request file. See the gcloud documentation for more information.
>
> Note: The storageSource and repoSource fields described in the Build resource documentation differ from the source field. storageSource instructs Container Builder to find the source files in a Cloud Storage bucket, and repoSource refers to a Cloud Source Repository containing the source files.

So how, then, do you specify repoSource with gcloud? I am only seeing the gs:// url prefix documented.

Comment: This is not currently supported today. The gcloud surface only supports building from local source, which is uploaded to Cloud Storage and built from there as a `storageSource`, or using `--no-source` in which case no source is specified.

Comment: Thanks @JasonHall. So I should use curl to submit a build request with a source?

Comment: Yeah, that's the best way today.

Comment: The `gcloud` tool is great and it would be nice if I could use it. Is there a way I can feature request this?

Comment: For some alternatives, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48962597/triggering-a-build-for-a-specific-git-commit-via-gcloud-commandline-tool